# Steam app not launch on X11

Tags: xorg, games, steam, login-screen, wayland

I can play games from Steam only in Wayland. However, this displaying does not support screen recorders.
Is it any solution to launch Steam  in X11 session ?

I tried edit on  `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` / by uncomment # and wayland=true / to working in Wayland under X11, but nothing change.

In brief, Steam not launch in X11 and screen recorders not working with Wayland.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the info on this site. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/sggll4/i_heard_steam_deck_and_steam_os_is_going_to_use/

Comment: In other Distros it is working ( Zorin, Pop OS )

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: It means, it is possible.

Comment: No it means on those OS it is. They are not Ubuntu.

Comment: Steam from the Ubuntu repos works fine in both X and Wayland for me.  If you start steam in a terminal, do the messages give any indication of a problem?  All games or just some have problems?  does xrandr --listproviders give the gpus in the expected order, or are they reversed (fix with power setting or some env variables)?

Comment: No. It appears like it's fine and running in backround...I can launch steam app and play games only in Wayland. My X11 Terminal: steam

steam.sh[6174]: Running Steam on Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit

steam.sh[6174]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

setup.sh[6310]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date! steam.sh[6174]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied ... It's just not displayed because X11 is not supported and screen recorders was managed and programmed only for X11 session type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only choice was  install OBS studio from Flathub.

Answer (score 0):

What screen recorders do you use? There are a lot of screen recorders for Wayland to help your cause, for example, [Kooha](https://ubunlog.com/en/kooha-graba-tu-pantalla-de-manera-sencilla/), [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) and [Blue Recorder](https://github.com/xlmnxp/blue-recorder) just to name a few.

Also, if your GNOME version isn't too old, you should be able to press PrintScreen (the `PrtSc` button), and just click the little webcam icon to switch to screencast recording.

Comment: I like to record games. Actually I am using OBS and Kden live.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem now on Ubuntu 23.04. What worked for me was to launch Steam from terminal as follows:

```
steam -cef-disable-gpu
```

Other potential workarounds for this problem are discussed here:

https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/9780